# Can clients send email to each other via your website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, mailmessage

I am working on an online shopping website. I want the users directly contact each other via emails by using a web form. I have tried different ways. but it didn't work. 
I was also trying to use the gmail smtp as follow:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "mypassword");
 client.EnableSsl = true;
string fromAddress = "buyer@gmail.com";
string messageSubject = "Your Subject";
string body = "Content";
var supEmail = "seller@yahoo.com";
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(fromAddress, supEmail, messageSubject, body);
            MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("notifications@mydomain.com");
            mm.CC.Add(copy);
            //Set up your encoding
            mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            //Send your message
            client.Send(mm);
```

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the settings on your google account? Do you have 2-factor enabled? Have you tried generating an application specific password? Have you tried disabling SSL?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Google won't allow you to send an email from an account you don't own... so if you want to send an email via Google then it needs to be from either the Google email account your are validating with or associated with that account.